# MySQLでのデータディレクトリ変更

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.6, CentoOS6.4を使用しているのですが、MySQLのデータディレクトリの移動が出来ません。

やったこと

- mysqlサーバーを停止してから、デフォルトのデータフォルダから移動先のデータフォルダへファイル・ディレクトリを全てコピーし、chownで新ディレクトリの所有者をmysql:mysqlに変更
- /etc/my.cnfを作成し、[client], [mysqld]のdatadir, pid-file, socketを移動先のフォルダにあわせて設定

症状

- mysqlサーバーを起動するためにservice mysql startをコマンドラインで入力すると、下記のメッセージが表示される

Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/new_datadir/***.localhost.pid).

- /new_datadir/***.localhost.errの内容は下記の通り

151012 16:40:34 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /new_datadir
151012 16:40:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /new_datadir/***.localhost.pid ended

- /etc/my.cnfを消去すると、mysqlサーバーはデフォルトのデータフォルダで問題なく起動する。

様々なサイトを調べたのですが、どうしても自力で解決できません。
また、getenforceの返り値はPermissiveだったので、SELinux関係のトラブルではないと思います
よろしくお願いします。

追記
[このサイト](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-MySQL-Configuration_Examples.html)にしたがって移動先のディレクトリとファイルのタイプを'unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0'に変更しましたが、改善できませんでした。

Comment: 移動先のデータフォルダへのコピーはどの様にして行いましたか？ もしかして、移動先データフォルダの中のサブディレクトリやファイルのオーナ・グループが root になっていたりしませんか？

Comment: コピーした後に、chownで所有者・グループをmysql:mysqlに変更しています

Comment: ええと、つまり `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql new_datadir` を実行した、ということですね？

Comment: はい、そのとおりです。ls -lで所有者が変わっていることも確認しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。お手間を取らせてしまってすみませんでした。

Comment: 参考になるかも [How to change MySQL data directory? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーログファイルに、mysqld_safe のログしか出ていないようです。mysqld のエラーがどこかに出力されているのではないかと思います。

mysqld --help --verbose で出力される log-error の値がどのファイルになっているかを確認し、そのファイルの中にエラーが出力されていないか確認してみるのが良いと思います。

それでもわからなければ、mysqld_safe ではなく直接 mysqld を起動してみると何かわかるかもしれません。

もし例示されている /new_datadir/ が実際には複数のパス要素(/new/data/dir/ 等)で構成されているとしたら、各ディレクトリのパーミッションを調べてみるのも良いと思います。`ls -ld / /new /new/data /new/data/dir` のように。

Comment: 直接mysqldを起動してみたところ、

2015-10-12 18:44:19 17121 [Warning] Can't create test file /new_datadir/***.lower-test
2015-10-12 18:44:19 17121 [Warning] Can't create test file /new_datadir/***.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/new_datadir/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

SELinux関係で問題がある時に同様のエラーがでるようですが、getenforceで確認するとPermissiveなんですよね...

Comment: もし例示されている /new_datadir/ が実際には複数のパス要素(/new/data/dir/ 等)で構成されているとしたら、各ディレクトリのパーミッションを調べてみるのも良いと思います。ls -ld / /new /new/data /new/data/dir のように。

Comment: 実際のパスは/media/HDD1/new_dirとなっています。所有者はルートから、root、root、User1、mysqlとなっていました。デフォルトのデータフォルダ、/var/lib/mysqlの所有者はroot、root、mysqlなので、間にUser1が所有者のディレクトリが入っていることが問題なのでしょうか?

Comment: mysqlユーザにアクセス権が無いんだろうと推測しますが、パーミションはどうなってますか？オーナーが User1 でもアクセス権があれば問題ないはずです。

Comment: /var/lib/mysqlと、/media/HDD1/new_datadirのパーミッションを見比べ、HDD1ディレクトリにchmod +rxしたら起動できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @organic.WV コメントだと解決方法が埋もれてしまうので、後からここにたどり着いた人のためにも、改めて回答として投稿していただけませんか。

Comment: @holywise 投稿しました。

Answer (score 2):

コメントだと解決法が埋もれてしまうというご指摘があったので、回答として解決法を投稿します。

移動先のデータディレクトリが複数のパス、例えば/new/data/dir、で構成されてる場合には、「/」「/new」「/new/data」「/new/data/dir」の全てにr権限が必要のようです。
下記のように各ディレクトリにパーミッションを与えることで解決できます。

```
chmod +r / /new /new/data /new/data/dir
```

権限が変更されたことはls -ldで確認できます。

```
ls -ld / /new /new/data /new/data/dir
dr-xr-xr-x. 28 root  root  4096 Sep 24 11:43 /
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root  root  4096 Oct 14 22:23 /new
drwxr-xr-x. 27 User1  User1  4096 Oct 12 16:14 /new/data
drwxr-xr-x.  5 mysql mysql 4096 Oct 15 10:42 /new/data/dir/
```

これで起動できるようになりました。

Answer (score 0):

/new_datadir/ 以下の `ls -l` の結果が書かれてないので当てずっぽうですが
root が作成した pid ファイルが残ってませんか？

Comment: lsで確認しましたが、pidファイルは残っていませんでした。